Does the maximal function of a positive function say away from zero on bounded sets?
I was reading the book "Fourier Analysis" by J. Duoandikoetxea and D. Cruz-Uribe. In one of the results, they want to prove the following weighted inequality:

Theorem (Weighted Inequality): For non-negative measurable function $w$, and $1 < p < \infty$, we have
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left( Mf \left( x \right) \right)^p w \left( x \right) \mathrm{d}x \leq C \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left| f \left( x \right) \right| Mw \left( x \right) \mathrm{d}x.$$
And, for $p = 1$, we have the following weak-type inequality
$$\int\limits_{\left\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n | Mf \left( x \right) > \lambda \right\rbrace} w \left( x \right) \mathrm{d}x \leq \frac{C}{\lambda} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left| f \left( x \right) \right| Mw \left( x \right) \mathrm{d}x.$$

The idea for this proof is to observe that we already have the $L^{\infty}-L^{\infty}$ bound (with weights), and to prove the weak $(1, 1)$ inequality stated in the theorem. However, in the proof of the weak $(1, 1)$ inequality, the authors want to use the Calderon-Zygmund decomposition for an $L^1$-function $f$. However, from what we want, we should start with a function $f \in L^1 \left( Mw \right)$.
In the text, the authors mention that for such functions, we can look at the sequence $f_j = f \chi_{B \left( 0, j \right)}$, which are $L^1$ and increase to $f$ pointwise. What I don't understand here is how do we conclude that $f_j \in L^1$? I have tried the following:
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_j \left( x \right) \mathrm{d}x = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} f \left( x \right) Mw \left( x \right) \frac{1}{Mw \left( x \right)} \chi_{B \left( 0, j \right)} \left( x \right) \mathrm{d}x.$$
Therefore, to prove our claim, it is sufficient to prove that $\frac{1}{Mw \left( x \right)}$ is bounded on $B (0, j )$. This is equivalent to proving that there is some $c > 0$ such that for all $x \in B (0, j)$, we have $Mw ( x ) \geq c$.
If this is not true, then there is a sequence $\left( x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in the set $B(0, j)$ such that $Mw(x_n) \rightarrow 0$. From here, I can only conclude that there is a subsequence $\left( x_{n_k} \right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ that converges in $\overline{B \left( 0, j \right)}$, and that $w (x_n ) \rightarrow 0$.
However, I am unable to get any contradiction from here. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

EDIT: A POSSIBLE SOLUTION
Till, now, we have seen that there is a convergent subsequence $\left( x_{n_k} \right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\overline{B \left( 0, j \right)}$ such that $Mw \left( x_{n_k} \right) \rightarrow 0$. By passing on to this subsequence, we will use $\left( x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ as our notation.
Now, let $x_n \rightarrow x_0$. For any $r > 0$ (fixed), there is some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$, we have $\| x_n - x_0 \| < r$. Particularly, we would have $B \left( x_n, 2r \right) \supseteq B \left( x_0, r \right)$.
Also, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq n_1$, we have $\sup\limits_{R > 0} \left\lbrace \frac{1}{\left| B \left( x_n, R \right) \right|} \int\limits_{B \left( x_n, R \right)} w \left( y \right) \mathrm{d}y \right\rbrace = Mw \left( x_n \right) < \varepsilon$.
Particularly, choosing $n = \max \left\lbrace n_0, n_1 \right\rbrace$, we would have $B \left( x_n, 2r \right) \subseteq B \left( x_0, r \right)$, and $\frac{1}{\left| B \left( x_n, 2r \right) \right|} \int\limits_{B \left( x_n, 2r \right)} w \left( y \right) \mathrm{d}y < \varepsilon$.
Consequently, we have
$$\frac{1}{\left| B \left( x_0, r \right) \right|} \int\limits_{B \left( x_0, r \right)} w \left( y \right) \mathrm{d}y \leq \frac{2^n}{\left| B \left( x_n, 2r \right) \right|} \int\limits_{B \left( x_n, 2r \right)} w \left( y \right) \mathrm{d}y < 2^n \varepsilon.$$
Since $\varepsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, we conclude that
$$\int\limits_{B \left( x_0, r \right)} w \left( y \right) \mathrm{d}y = 0.$$
That is, $w \equiv 0$ almost everywhere on $B \left( x_0, r \right)$. Again, since $r > 0$ was arbitrary, we are forced to conclude that $w \equiv 0$ almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is the desired contradiction we were aiming at!
Is this solution correct?
